# SharePoint 2013 : Can't find ULS .log or the .log directory

Tags: sharepoint

Can someone help me to locate the .log file in sharepoint 2013. I tried to locate it in directory: C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS , but there are no .logs file or log folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What is the configured path of the Trace Log ?
To check that, please
- Open the Central Administration
- In Central Administration, on the home page, click Monitoring.
- on the Monitoring page, in the Reporting section, click Configure diagnostic logging
- on the page Diagnostic Logging, there is a setting for the path of the Trace Log

The path set there is where you will find the ULS Log!

You could also use PowerShell to check this setting, please see [Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx) for details

Comment: Thanks on this guide. Will try it first. :)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 logs are stored in the 15 hive. You need to look in the folder named 15, not 14, in the path you mention.